# Java arrange array

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following array:

```
{x1, null, null, null, y1, null, null, null, z1, x2, null, null, null, y2, null, null, null, z2, x3, null, null, null, y3, null, null, null, z3}
```

and I need to arrange it like this:

```
{x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3}
```

Can you help me please? I have no idea how to start it.

Comment: Iterate the array and if the element is null delete it.

Answer (score 5):

I would follow these steps:

1. Loop through the array. Add each non-null element to a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
2. Use the [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method to create a new array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by array you mean some sort of `List`. If so, use an iterator, I'm assuming x1 is of class Integer:

```
Iterator<Integer> arrayIt = arrayIt.iterator();
while(arrayIt.hasNext()){
    if(arrayIt.next() == null){
        arrayIt.remove();
    }
}
```

If your array is really large, it will run *much* faster if the array is implemented using a `LinkedList` rather than, say, an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are right, but if you need more quick copy, you can do something like the following. If your data contain chars, for exampleThis solution with work **ONLY** if the source array has 9*k elements i.e. 9, 18, 27,... etc. (as I understood your array is like that):

```
    char[] source = {'1', ' ', ' ',
            ' ', '2', ' ',
            ' ', ' ', '3',
            '4', ' ', ' ',
            ' ', '5', ' ',
            ' ', ' ', '6'};

    char[] target = new char[source.length / 3];
    int targetIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i += 9) {
        target[targetIndex++] = source[i + 0];
        target[targetIndex++] = source[i + 4];
        target[targetIndex++] = source[i + 8];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that:

1. Convert the array to a [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) using [`Arrays`' `asList` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

   ```
   Object[] objects = {new Object(), null, null, new Object(), null};
   List<Object> tempList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(objects));
   ```
2. Loop through `tempList`.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++)
   {
   ```
3. [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) the element from `tempList` if it is `null`.

   ```
       if(tempList.get(i) == null)
       {
           tempList.remove(i);
           i--;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Covert `tempList` back to an array using [`ArrayList`'s `toArray()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29).

   ```
   objects = tempList.toArray();
   ```

Here is a complete working example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class RemoveArrayNull
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object[] objects = new Object[] {new Object(), null, null, new Object(), null};
        objects = removeNull(objects);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objects));
    }

    static Object[] removeNull(Object[] objects)
    {
        List<Object> tempList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(objects));
        for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(tempList.get(i) == null)
            {
                tempList.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        return tempList.toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to rely on ready made java methods as these are created and tested properly.
Data type is although not clear from the array you specified,I am considering it as String

---

Code:-

---

```
String []elements = new String[]{"x1", null, null, null, "y1", null, null, null, "z1", "x2", null, null, null, "y2", null, null, null, "z2", "x3", null, null, null, "y3", null, null, null, "z3"};
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(elements));
set.remove(null);
```

Comment: A `HashSet` is unordered though - and this would also eliminate duplicate non-null elements.

Comment: Agree!Paul.Keeping that condition in mind it should better go with ArrayList and remove all null elements by iterating.